# Java lib for displaying pdf files

Tags: java, pdf, annotations, pdfrenderer, icepdf

I'm looking for a Java library to display pdf files and annotations contained in these pdf files. I tried pdfrenderer and icepdf, but none of the two display annotations (icepdf manages to display highlighted text at least).

Any hint is appreciated.

Cheers,
Max

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983730/java-pdf-renderer

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082327/java-library-for-pdf-rendering)

Comment: I read this post, but I couldn't find anything about annotations, so I wasn't sure which library would be suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS version of JPedal is free and does annotations http://www.jpedal.org/open_source_pdf_viewer_download.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you try out iText and Jasper Reports?

Comment: iText doesn't render as far as I know (it's used to create pdf files). Jasper, I have used for similar things as iText (pdf generation), but not for displaying pdfs.

Comment: Also check out http://pdfbox.apache.org/ - I have not used it, but have seen friends.

Comment: "This project allows creation of new PDF documents, manipulation of existing documents and the ability to extract content from documents." - from http://pdfbox.apache.org/. Again, it doesn't seem to render pdf files.

Comment: So assuming this is a desktop based application, cant you try to spit out the PDF as a stream(to one of the components that support HTML) as if you were rendering a webpage?

Comment: The idea is to jump to certain positions within the pdf file and show the text, so converting it to HTML isn't really an option...